# Quel qualificatif exprimerait l’idée d’une personne qui peine à rembourser une dette à un ami et qui accepterait une invitation au restaurant?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Un ami prétend qu’il n’a pas les moyens de me rembourser une dette mais il accepte une invitation de ma part au restaurant. Quel serait ou quels seraient les termes (traits particuliers) exprimant cette idée, servant à décrire son agissement. Et de mon point vue, de quelle façon devrais-je interpréter cette situation, quels mots ou groupes de mots devrais-je mettre sur cette situation pour la dépeindre et la lui faire entendre?

Comment: Peux-être qu'il pense que tu vas lui payer le restaurant, et donc il n'aura pas besoin de payer ? Il semble juste profiter de tout ce que tu lui donnes

Comment: Ce n’est pas le cas, car je n’ai pas l’habitude de prendre sur moi les additions…

Comment: Ce serait être inconséquent dans ses propos que d’accepter l’invitation?

Comment: Pas forcément, je pense que ça change en fonction du niveau de la dette. Plus c'est faible, plus c'est incohérent. Car si tu dois par ex. 2000€, pourquoi refuser une invitation a passer un bon moment avec quelqu'un qui va te couter 30€?

Comment: Il dit ne pas avoir d’argent quand ça l’arrange, mais il en a bizarrement pour payer ses sorties, ne serait-ce pas là un flagrant délit de mensonge? Et que dire de quelqu’un qui ment à son propre ami? Qu’il est est irrespectueux à son égard?

Comment: Supposons qu’il soit invité dans un restaurant gastronomique où les plats ont la réputation d’être chers, comment décrire sa manière d’être et quels mots devrais-je mettre sur la situation ?

Comment: Ah, si tu as clairement dis aller dans un endroit cher, et qu'il n'a pas montré une retissence de type "Es-tu sûr d'aller ici ?" c'est compliqué. Je ne sais pas s'il y a un mot précis pour ça, peut-être que "profiteur"/"radin"/"rat"

Comment: Quand on **invite** quelqu'un au restaurant, ça veut dire qu'on est prêt à payer l'addition, sinon, on dit autre chose comme, proposer de se retrouver dans un restaurant.

Comment: Malhonnête? Ce serait être malhonnête que d’accepter l’invitation au restaurant?

Comment: Par chez moi, « inviter » peut être compris de plusieurs façons.

Comment: Chaque fois que l’on m’a « invité », je devais régler ma facture et chacun des convives faisait de même.

Comment: En revanche, quand on me conviait à un souper se déroulant dans le domicile de celui qui m’invitait chez lui, je n’avais pas à payer.

Comment: Et avec raison, sinon ce serait la première et dernière fois que j’accepterais une invitation de la part de cette personne.

Comment: Une *invitation payante* est un concept étrange pour moi. Si tu viens en France et invite vingt personnes au restaurant, ils risquent d'avoir une surprise à la fin du repas, et toi aussi...

Comment: @jlliagre  C’est toujours bon à savoir!

Comment: Voilà comment faire un *invitation* où on n'invite pas : *On se fait une bouffe chez Roger la Grenouille jeudi soir, ça te dis de venir ?*

Comment: Votre ami est un profiteur, point. De l'autre côté, quand on invite, il y a le sous-entendu que l'on réglera l'addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si c'est un ami, vous ne devriez même pas vous poser cette question.

Dans le cas contraire, la véritable question est « est-ce votre ami ? ».

C'est le sens de l'expression « bouffer à tous les râteliers ».

Pour ma part je qualifierais cet « ami » de :

**Parasite**

> ***PÉJORATIF***
>
> Personne qui vit dans l'oisiveté, aux dépens d'une communauté ou d'une
> autre personne. nom et adjectif

---

> ***nom masculin***
>
> Être qui ***vit aux dépens d'un autre (hôte) sans le détruire*** (ex. le
> pou, le ténia).

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL.  Il est important d'attribuer les citations  (un lien au dico suffira si possible).

Comment: Ouch, parasite me semble un peu intense.

Answer (score 1):

Je me sens obligé d'ajouter une réponse car même si *parasite* fonctionne, il y a une énorme connotation négative. Un parasite doit être exterminé, c'est une peste. Si tu veux en parler avec la personne et que tu la qualifies de parasite, c'est une insulte et ton amitié est probablement terminée.

De façon plus générale, comme plusieurs personnes l'ont déjà mentionné, on va parler d'un **[profiteur](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/profiteur/)**:

> Personne qui tire profit de choses ou de personnes, sans aucun scrupule.

Avec ce terme, tu peux lui en parler et lui dire que tu as l'impression qu'elle *profite* de toi, sans t'attendre à ce qu'elle soit insultée, sauf si évidemment elle n'est pas du même avis et c'est une personne sensible.